# Amazon ec2 can't send push notification on ios

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, push-notification

I am using below php code in Amazon ec2, php 7

```
<?php
    function sendApplePushNotificationMessage( $data, $message )
    {
        global $notification;
        $apns_settings = $notification['apns_user'];
        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apns_settings['pemFile']);
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.'.(($apns_settings['environment'] == $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect amarnew: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
        echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default'
        );
        $payload = json_encode($body+$extra_values);
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $data['token']) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        if (!$result)
            echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
            echo 'Message successfully delivered '.$message. PHP_EOL;   
        // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

when i call this function i got below success message.

```
Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered
```

When i try same pem file and device token to test online then it works properly but ***not work on Amazon ec2***.

Comment: Are you saying that when you run this code on your own computer, it works successfully, but it does not run successfully from Amazon EC2? What is the error message. Does your EC2 instance have permissions assigned via an IAM Role?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, when i run this code in Godaddy dedicated linux server then successfully deliver notification message. but when i run this code in EC2 then i got response message like "Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered" but notification message doesn't deliver to ios device.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sorry, what you mean by"EC2 instance have permissions assigned via an IAM Role?"

Comment: When a Role is assigned to an Amazon EC2 at launch, credentials will be provided to applications that run on that instance. See: [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `APN` service to send push notifications . It will access ports `2195` & `2196` to send push notifications using `TCPSocket` internally.

Your local system will have access to all ports, then there will be  no problem.

`EC2` instance in default doesn't have access to those ports. You can allow/open those ports in your `ec2` instance `security groups`.

Also allow port `443` .

Comment: is it in inbound rules?

Comment: @Maulik : yes exactly

Comment: Ok , Fine then.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to writing your own function to cause an Apple Push Notification would be to use Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS).

**Amazon SNS** can push notifications to iOS, Android, Baidu, Windows mobile, Windows desktop and Mac desktop.

See: [Getting Started with Apple Push Notification Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html)

Comment: you are right that Amazon SNS is alternative way for this but i need to know what wrong with EC2 server or why this code cant deliver message?